# JSF – how to prevent fields from being overwritten on update

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

This is one step in a flow and I would like to check whether there is a record for a customer with given `idNumber`. In such a case I would like to populate remaining fields with data from database.

I was tracing the running application and I saw that `currentCustomer`’s fields has been filled with data from the db only to be immediately overwritten with empty strings as a result of calls to `getCustomer…` (returning `""`) and `setCustomer…` (writing `""`) methods invoked immediately after pressing the AJAX button.

I assume there is something fundamentally wrong with my current approach to solution of the problem so I would appreciate any advice on how to handle such a situation properly.

I have form like this:

### order-travellers.xml

```xml
<h:outputLabel for="idNumber" value="ID: "/>
<h:inputText id="idNumber" value=“#{orderBean.customerIdNumber}" required="true"/>
<a4j:commandButton value="update" reRender="surname"/>
<br/>
<h:outputLabel for="firstName" value="First name: "/>
<h:inputText id="firstName" value="#{orderBean.customerFirstName}"/>
<br/>
<h:outputLabel for="surname" value="Surname: "/>
<h:inputText id="surname" value="#{orderBean.customerSurname}"/>
```

and backing bean like this:

### orderBean.java

```
@Named
@FlowScoped("order")
public class orderBean implements Serializable {
private Customer currentCustomer = new Customer();
private List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<>();

private Customer knownCustomer(String id) {
    …
    Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(Customer.class);
    cr.add(Restrictions.eq("idNumber",id));
    List<Customer> results = cr.list();

    if (results.isEmpty()) return currentCustomer;
    else return results.get(0);
}

public String getCustomerIdNumber() {
    return currentCustomer.getIdNumber();
}

public void setCustomerIdNumber(String idNumber) {
    currentCustomer = knownCustomer(idNumber);
    currentCustomer.setIdNumber(idNumber);
}

public String getCustomerFirstName() {
    return currentCustomer.getFirstName();
}

public void setCustomerFirstName(String firstName) {
    currentCustomer.setFirstName(firstName);
}

public String getCustomerSurname() {
    return currentCustomer.getSurname();
}

public void setCustomerSurname(String surname) {
    currentCustomer.setSurname(surname);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I understood question like this form is bringing some values from DB then it is resetting all the value to empty if that is the case try

> process="@form"

in your button might be will solve your problem although it's not good approach to use so many process in your page but i think for your case it would be okay.

Comment: I think this only works with PrimeFaces while I am using RichFaces. However you were right that there was a problem with ajax. I changed the relevant line to `<a4j:ajax event="blur" render="firstName surname" execute="@this"/>` what seem to have fixed the issue.